# setOnFocusChangeListener results in a 'cannot resolve symbol' error

Tags: android-edittext

While trying to use the 'setOnFocusChangeListener' to intercept the event of an EditText view getting focus, I keep getting the 'cannot resolve symbol' error. Tried searching for solutions here as well as other sites on the 'net. Hence posting the question here. Pasting the code below:

```
EditText fromDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valid_from);
OnFocusChangeListener lis = new OnFocusChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v,    boolean hasFocus){
        if (hasFocus ) {
            showDatePicker();
        }
    }
};

fromDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(lis) ;

private void showDatePicker() {
    DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
    /**
     * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
     */
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();  [..and so on]
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have imported android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue and i fixed it by.

- Make your (Activity || Fragment) `Implements OnFocusChangeListener`.
- Put your business inside `onFoacusChange` method.

  > ```
  > @Override
  > public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  > if(!hasFocus)
  >     return;
  > switch (v.getId()){
  >     case R.id.valid_from:
  >     showDatePicker();
  >     break;
  > }
  > }
  > ```

**Update**

```
fromDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Tried this solution. It does not give me an error any more, but neither does it give the expected result. In short, nothing happens when the valid_from editText field gets focus. Anyway, I have found a workaround by disabling the focus (setting both _focusable_ and _focusableInTouchMode_ properties to 'false'). Instead, I am displaying a calendar icon for the purpose. That works pretty well.

Comment: @SanjayDeshpande You have to set `OnFocusChangeListener` to your view. Please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

use `View.OnFocusChangeListener()` instead of `OnFocusChangeListener`

e.g.

`mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    // code to execute when EditText loses focus
                }
            }
        });`